# jenkins while creating folder access denied using base clear case

Tags: build, jenkins, continuous-integration, clearcase

I am trying to build make file using xshell plugin in jenkins.

Manually, I am able to build, but when I trigger from jenkins I get bellow error please suggest why access is denied:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * /main/LATEST
[workspace] $ cmd.exe /C '""V:\dpush_view\CCAD_REPO\CC Training\my\one.bat" && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'

D:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\nmake\workspace>v:

V:\>cd "dpush_view\CCAD_REPO\CC Training\my" 

V:\dpush_view\CCAD_REPO\CC Training\my>nmake vivek1.mk 

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 7.10.3077
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    mkdir "V:\dpush_view\CCAD_REPO\CC Training\ball\sree"
Access is denied.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'mkdir' : return code '0x1'
Stop.

V:\dpush_view\CCAD_REPO\CC Training\my>pause
Press any key to continue . . . 
Build step 'Invoke XShell command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure  of the account used by Jenkins to use that ClearCase view.

If Jenkins runs with the system account, chances are that `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` isn't properly set, and it wouldn't have the right to fully access `CCAD_REPO` vobs elements.

So make sure it is running with your account (which, when used manually, can successfully build in that view).

---

The other aspect is in the rights associated with the parent folder where you try to create `ball\sree`:

Make sure (by doing a `cleartool descr -l "V:\dpush_view\CCAD_REPO\CC Training@@"`) that the folder is "executable" (755).

If not, a simple:

```
cleartool protect -chmod 755 "V:\dpush_view\CCAD_REPO\CC Training@@"
```

If `"V:\dpush_view\CCAD_REPO\CC Training\ball@@"` already exists (and Jenkins is trying to create sre within ball folder, repeat the checks (`cleartool describe` and, if need be, `cleartool protect -chmod`)

Note in both instances the presence of '`@@`': it is to reference the element folder '`CC Training`' (instead of the version).

Comment: i am already done what you say but the same error will come please give me another solution

Comment: @user3567732 is "`V:\dpush_view`" a dynamic or snapshot view? Does the folder '`ball`' already exist when you do the `mkdir ball\sree`?

Comment: @user3567732 can you create it (just '`ball`') manually, and try again your Jenkins job? Again, make sure your Jenkins runs as you, with `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

start the Jenkins service as respective users

by using **services.msc** in run command

Comment: So it was a user account issue, as I suggested in my answer?